# not able to draw rect on existing <canvas> which rendered PDF using pdfjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, pdf.js

**Task**

Have a canvas in your page
`<canvas id="pdfCanvas">`
create a fabric canvas for existing canvas
`new fabric.Canvas("pdfCanvas");`
have mouse.down, mouse.up, mouse.move methods to enable drawing rectangles
render pdf in the above canvas "pdfCanvas" using PDF.js
browser now shows the rendered PDF
now draw rectangles on the pdf, it hides the rendered canvas but it does draw objects

**Problem**

Here is the fiddle to see the issue:
- run the above https://jsfiddle.net/hiitskiran/wgz8qore/2/
- you can see the fabric rectangle is hiding behind the rendered pdf
- click on the pdf canvas area to see the fabric objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I see from your fiddle is that you don't wait the result of `page.render` method, which is asyncronous, then, unfortunately, if you wait the `page.render`, the fabric.canvas instance will clean your previously filled canvas, and we can't do nothing for this.
So I tried another approach: First of all, I wait the pdf.js `page.render` method, then I invoke the .toDataURL of your previously filled canvas so that I can have a copy of the old content, then I set your previously filled canvas as background of your new fabric.canvas and finish to draw your rectangle.

```js
var url = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';
var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfcanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function(pdf) {
  pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    page.render({
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    }).then(function() {

      var bg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var fcanvas = new fabric.Canvas("pdfcanvas", {
        selection: false
      });
   fcanvas.setBackgroundImage(bg,fcanvas.renderAll.bind(fcanvas));
      fcanvas.setWidth(300);
      fcanvas.setHeight(300);
      var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: '#FF454F',
        opacity: 0.5,
        transparentCorners: true,
        borderColor: "gray",
        cornerColor: "gray",
        cornerSize: 5
      });
      fcanvas.add(rect);
      fcanvas.renderAll();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://seikichi.github.io/tmp/PDFJS.0.8.715/pdf.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="pdfcanvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Inferon, I actually tried using the same setbackgroundImage, but what I missed is the key thing, I didnt realized page.render() is a promise so I had my code immediately after page.render() so since its an asynchronous call it wasnt working for me.  Is this the only way to do it, every time a new page is rendered set it as a background image?  Glad I setup a fiddle else it wudve been difficult to explain the issue.

Comment: I think it is the only way, but if you can obtain an svg from your pdf.js it should be another story, best regard

Comment: When I asked the question in github asturur replied below : i guess that having a separate canvas for fabric to display what you want to display, to overlay over pdfjs canvas, saves a draw operation, to redraw the background ( pdfpage ) everytime you do something on the fabric canvas.
Please for this kind of questions open stackoverlow question and in case ping me directly, but is not an issue we can track here.   How do we overlay canvas over canvas? I didnt find an example how to do do that, when I had 2 canvases, one for pdfjs to render and another one for fabric js i cant draw

Comment: how can I change the size of the view dynamically with 2 buttons that are fit page and fit width? Suppose if I change after finding scaling factor then what about the size of the fabric objects inside canvas? how to scale those objects?

Comment: @InferOn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608971/how-to-draw-rectangle-in-canvas-which-is-already-in-pdf-js?noredirect=1#comment86251263_49608971 could you pls help me in this issue